# Não consigo achar o problema no código

Tags: c

Fiz um código em C que ao executar apresenta alguns erros e possivelmente não seja erro de lógica, já que quando eu executo apresenta alguns erros, entretanto, quando peço para um amigo executar o código funciona normalmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código pega a primeira letra de cada vetor, cria e coloca em outro vetor fazendo o mesmo com as letras seguintes, mas está aparecendo essa resposta.

esse é o código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * JuntarVetores(char * v1, char *v2, char* v3);
void main()
{
    char A[80],B[80],C[80];
    char *D;

    printf("Vetor A: ");
    scanf("%s",A);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Vetor B: ");
    scanf("%s",B);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Vetor C: ");
    scanf("%s",C);

    D=JuntarVetores(A,B,C);

    printf("%s",D);

}

char * JuntarVetores(char * v1, char *v2, char* v3)
{
    int i,x1=0,x2=0,x3=0;
    char *v4=(char*)malloc((strlen(v1)+strlen(v2)+strlen(v3)) * sizeof(char));

    for(i=0;i<strlen(v1)||i<strlen(v2)||i<strlen(v3);i++)
    {
        if(v1[i]!='\0' && x1==0)
        {
            *(v4+strlen(v4))=*(v1+i);
           // printf("1");
        }
        else
            x1=1;

        if(v2[i]!='\0' && x2==0)
        {
            *(v4+strlen(v4))=*(v2+i);
            //printf("2");
        }
        else
            x2=1;

        if(v3[i]!='\0' && x3==0)
        {
            *(v4+strlen(v4))=*(v3+i);
            //printf("3");
        }
        else
            x3=1;
    }

    return(v4);
}
```

Comment: O problema nunca é do compilador. Ou você acha que depois de décadas que milhões de pessoas usando ninguém viu um problema em um código tão simples e você que está começando agora já achou esse problema? Olhando por isso eu vi vários problemas no código, mas vou sair agora e com tantos problemas pra mim a pergunta é ampla demais para responder.

Comment: de forma alguma eu acho q sou alguem foda, só estou com um problema q n consigo resolver, posso ter errado a forma de escrever o titulo, mas eu n entedi pq ser tao esnobe

Comment: Note que você aloca memória para `v4` mas no coloca nada nesta memória. Creio que queira que inicialmente `v4` seja uma string de comprimento zero, neste caso faça `v4[0] = '\0'`. Seu código está bastante confuso mas creio que bastaria um contador para v4, que seria incrementado até a concatenação de todos os outros arrays e um outro contador a ser utilizado para percorrer cada um dos arrays a serem concatenados. Não há necessidade de utilizar a função `strlen`, basta lembrar que uma string em C termina com o caractere `'\0'`.

Comment: obrigado, vou tentar

Comment: @KaioSato você quer algo mais esnobe que dizer que o compilador tá errado e você está certo? Eu tentei te mostrar que essa atitude não funciona, você tem todo direito de ignorar e continuar assim. Algumas pessoas pegam essa informação e aprendem.

Comment: eu n entendo de computação/programação, qnd disse q estava aparecendo respostas diferentes num mesmo código, a minha intuição diz q tem algo de errado ( e no caso EU achei q seria o compilador, já que o código era o mesmo, como já falei n entendo porra nenhuma), no caso do titulo vc poderia ter dito diretamente pra ter mudado, e como já me responderam, vou ficar com o beneficio da duvida e assumir q EU possa ter te interpretado mal.

Answer (score 2):

É uma característica do C, que um bug no programa vai se manifestar de forma bem diferente em computadores diferentes, ou mesmo executando várias vezes no mesmo computador.

No caso específico do seu programa, parece que você não está deixando espaço para o \0 final da string, nem está atribuindo \0 ao último byte. Toda string em C tem de ser terminada em \0. As strings que o scanf() está preenchendo para você, ele faz a terminação, por isso o programa funciona até certo ponto.

O espaço total da string final, alocada com malloc() tem de ser a soma das 3, mais 1, para acomodar o \0 no final. E você precisa atribuir esse zero explicitamente, ou então usar calloc() em vez de malloc() pois o calloc() zera a memória alocada, enquanto o malloc() não.

Comment: obrigado pela explicacao

Comment: exatamente, pela resposta do epx, você entendeu, que com calloc() sempre a memória alocada está limpa, com malloc() não, por isso, algumas situações ele encontra a memoria vazia e não apresenta o erro, quando o espaço contém um valor, o erro aparece.....